# Error on Compiling matconvnet on windows

Tags: matlab, matconvnet

I'm trying to compile matconvnet on Windows using [this](http://www.vlfeat.org/matconvnet/quick/) link. However I'm stuck at:

```
>> run matlab/vl_compilenn('EnableImreadJpeg',false,'verbose',1) ;
```

Which gives me a long list of errors,  of which I'm copying a few lines:

```
Error using mex
C:\WINDOWS\system32\matconvnet-1.0-beta25\matlab\mex\.build\vl_nnconv.obj:vl_nnconv.cpp:(.xdata+0x80): undefined reference to
`__gxx_personality_seh0'
C:\WINDOWS\system32\matconvnet-1.0-beta25\matlab\mex\.build\bits\data.obj:data.cpp:(.text+0x11a): undefined reference to
`__cxa_guard_acquire'
C:\WINDOWS\system32\matconvnet-1.0-beta25\matlab\mex\.build\bits\data.obj:data.cpp:(.text+0x1e9): undefined reference to
`__cxa_guard_release'
C:\WINDOWS\system32\matconvnet-1.0-beta25\matlab\mex\.build\bits\data.obj:data.cpp:(.text+0x5a8): undefined reference to `operator
delete(void*)'
C:\WINDOWS\system32\matconvnet-1.0-beta25\matlab\mex\.build\bits\data.obj:data.cpp:(.text+0x5ec): undefined reference to
`std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_assign(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char,
std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
C:\WINDOWS\system32\matconvnet-1.0-beta25\matlab\mex\.build\bits\data.obj:data.cpp:(.text+0x609): undefined reference to `operator
delete(void*)'
C:\WINDOWS\system32\matconvnet-1.0-beta25\matlab\mex\.build\bits\data.obj:data.cpp:(.text+0xb3f): undefined reference to
`std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_append(char const*, unsigned long long)'
C:\WINDOWS\system32\matconvnet-1.0-beta25\matlab\mex\.build\bits\data.obj:data.cpp:(.text+0xb4d): undefined reference to
`std::__throw_length_error(char const*)'
 C:\WINDOWS\system32\matconvnet-1.0-beta25\matlab\mex\.build\bits\impl\tinythread.obj:tinythread.cpp:(.xdata+0xd4): undefined
reference to `__gxx_personality_seh0'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status


Error in vl_compilenn>mex_link (line 627)
mex(args{:}) ;

Error in vl_compilenn (line 500)
  mex_link(opts, objs, flags.mex_dir, flags) ;
```

I have searched a lot on the internet, but I'm unable to find a solution for this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's the  output of `vl_compilenn('verbose', 1)`?

Comment: @HosseinKa I have updated the output

Comment: What does `mex -setup` return? This looks to me like a compiler incompatibility. If not already the case, I would attempt using a supported compiler listed on the MathWorks website.